# Accessing child class from parent class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

First of all I'm sorry if this is asked already but I couldn't find answer.

So, can I have class A and it inherits class B, can I access class A function from class B?

This is just example.

```
class A : public B
{
    void aFoo() { cout << "A" << endl; }
};

class B
{
    void bFoo() { aFoo(); }
};
```

So, is this possible in any way and if it is how it can be done?

Comment: Read something about virtual methods.

Comment: No, because then every class would need to know about all of its derived types, present and future.

Comment: That doesn't make sense: `B` doesn't have a method `aFoo`. What if you said `B b; b.bFoo();?`

Comment: Is there any concrete problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Maybe inheritance is not the way to model your solution. So please ask about the problem and not about what you think is the solution.

Comment: Technically, yes, base class can get access to derived classes.  However, this is counter-intuitive, goes against OO paradigms, and points to a fundamental problem in the design.  Rather than trying the above, go back to your problem and find a different (better) solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a virtual function in B and reimplement it in A, however you still have to create the object as A, for example:

```
class A : public B {
    void aFoo() { cout << "A" << endl; }
};

class B {
    void bFoo() { aFoo(); }
    virtual void aFoo() { cout << "B" << endl; } //or
    virtual void aFoo() = 0; // turning B into an abstract class.
};
.......
B* ab = new A;
```

Comment: Note that `B` doesn't have to implement `aFoo` it could be pure,  making `B` an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes (with templates)... You can use the Parent class as a template class which receieves the the Type of its child, so it can cast itself to that type... e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A() = default;

    void afoo()
    {
        reinterpret_cast<T*>(this)->bfoo();
    }
};


class B : public A<B>
{
public:
    B() = default;

    void bfoo()
    {
        std::cout << "In B::bfoo()";
    };
};


int main()
{

    B b;
    b.afoo();
}
```

This way you can avoid virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

> So, is this possible in any way and if it is how it can be done?

**No**. You can't. **Note that inheritance doesn't work in reverse**. The base class and its objects don’t know anything about any classes derived from the base class.

Answer (score 0):

No. Derived classes can access base class members and methods if declared public/protected. It does **not** work the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about whether it is possible syntactically, then as others have answered - No you can't because that's not how it works.

However, if you are looking for a design pattern to solve an issue in which this is something you would like to have, then I think what you are looking for is a **Bridge Pattern** where the parent class calls a virtual function which is implemented differently in each different child class (exactly what OneofOne answered).

More about the Bridge Pattern: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/bridge/cpp/1